# Writing to openssl's stdio in C using pipe

Tags: c, linux, openssl, pipe, exec

I am trying to pass some data to openssl like this:

```
int fd[2];
char buff[MAXBUFF];
pid_t childpid;
pipe(fd);

childpid = fork();

if (childpid == 0){
  dup2(0, fd[0]);
  close(fd[1]);
  execlp("openssl", "s_client", "-connect", "imap.gmail.com:993", "-crlf", NULL);
}
else {
  close(fd[0]);
  dosomething(buff);
  write(fd[1], buff, strlen(buff) + 1);
  sleep(4);
}
```

But it seems like openssl does not get data from buff, it just hangs waiting for some input I think.
If I do same thing with bash

a.sh:

```
.
.
.
echo $data
sleep 3
.
.
.
```

b.sh:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf
```

./a.sh | ./b.sh

everything works fine.

Comment: Can you try to flush the pipe?

Comment: does buff contain a trailing newline?

Comment: @orion78fr Well I tried to duplicate fd[1] to stdout in parent process and then use printf and fflush to write to pipe and it does not work again.

Comment: @Ctx Yes, it does .

Comment: @vacso Ok, then, why do you suspect that openssl doesn't receive the data at all? Is it possible that you misinterpret what you are observing?

Comment: @Ctx When I try to do this with bash output of openssl looks somewhat like this:
    `{lot of ssl stuff}
     OK Gimap ready for requests from *****
    * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1
    t001 OK ******* success
    .
    .
    .
    t003 OK good day (success)`

But with C version I get
`{lot of SSL stuf}
* OK Gimap ready for requests from **********
and here are printed contents of buff`
and then it exits.

Comment: @Ctx BTW. When i write to pipe without printf and stdout (like in OP) openssl outputs only `{lot of SSL stuff} * OK Gimap ready for requests from ` and exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You switched the arguments of `dup2()`.

The prototype is:

```
int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);
```

so you should do

```
dup2(fd[0], 0);
```

to set `fd[0]` as stdin of the child process. Then it should work as expected.